# include external java script file in jsp page 

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have an external JavaScript file named paging.js. Following are the contents of the file:

```
function Pager(tableName,itemPerPage){
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemPerPage = itemPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;

    this.init()= function(){
        alert("init called ");
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1);
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemPerPage);
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName,positionId){
        alert("show page navi call");
        var element = document.getElementById(positionId);
        var pagerHtml = '<input src = "next.jpg" type="image">';
        pagerHtml += '<input src = "next.jpg" type="image">' ;
        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
}
```

Now I tried to call init from my jsp page like .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        var pager = new Pager('results',7);
                        pager.init();
                    </script>
```

This code i put before complete my body part in my jsp page.

For including this page I put line like

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
                  src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/paging.js"></script>
```

But i can't able to call init method. Is there anyone to help me for finding problem?

Comment: How you are not able to call `init`? Have you tried in firebug? Can you see the javascript file loaded in browser?

Comment: yes if i put simple alert int the page its work fine

Comment: Yes you are right ,its work on IE.But why simple alert work and this not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is the problem:

```
this.init()= function(){
```

Change it to:

```
this.init=function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
                  src="js/paging.js"></script>
```

Comment: this may not work if the url is `http://baseurl/conextroot/somedir/myjsp.jsp` and JS is just under  context root.

Answer (score 0):

With .jsp 2.+ technology, I place all my links and scripts in a separate file that I reference using the `<jsp:include>` directive:

```
<jsp:include page="//path to your links_and_scripts page">
```

My links_and_scripts page has this `meta` and the path to my script:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="// path to your scripts js"></script>
//...your other scripts and links here
```